# whats similar like spring to execute hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(detachedCriteria) in struts & Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring

What's similar like spring to execute `hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(detachedCriteria)` in struts & Hibernate?

In spring we can execute `hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(detachedCriteria)` using  `HibernateTemplate` of Spring, but how can we execute that detached criteria using hibernate session?

`session.SOMETHING(detacherdCriteria);` OR something else ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got my answer:

```
detachedCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(session).list();
```